# polkit: disable all users except those in group wheel?

Tags: permissions, policykit

Is it possible to do the following using 1 polkit .pkla file?

1. Disable all users except those in the wheel group from using polkit.
2. The users in the wheel group will need to provide the root password when using polkit.

/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/99-wheel-only.pkla

```
[disable all users except the wheel group]
Identity=unix-group:wheel
Action=*
ResultAny=???
ResultInactive=???
ResultActive=???
```

The following file works but you need to provide all the users in /etc/group:

```
[disable all users except those in the wheel group: root and myuser]
Identity=unix-user:daemon;unix-user:bin;unix-user:sys;unix-user:adm;unix-user:tty;unix-user:disk;unix-user:lp;unix-user:mail;unix-user:news;unix-user:uucp;unix-user:man;unix-user:proxy;unix-user:kmem;unix-user:dialout;unix-user:fax;unix-user:voice;unix-user:cdrom;unix-user:floppy;unix-user:tape;unix-user:sudo;unix-user:audio;unix-user:dip;unix-user:www-data;unix-user:backup;unix-user:operator;unix-user:list;unix-user:irc;unix-user:src;unix-user:gnats;unix-user:shadow;unix-user:utmp;unix-user:video;unix-user:sasl;unix-user:plugdev;unix-user:staff;unix-user:games;unix-user:users;unix-user:nogroup;unix-user:libuuid;unix-user:crontab;unix-user:messagebus;unix-user:Debian-exim;unix-user:mlocate;unix-user:avahi;unix-user:netdev;unix-user:bluetooth;unix-user:lpadmin;unix-user:ssl-cert;unix-user:fuse;unix-user:utempter;unix-user:Debian-gdm;unix-user:scanner;unix-user:saned;unix-user:i2c;unix-user:haldaemon;unix-user:powerdev
Action=*
ResultAny=no
ResultInactive=no
ResultActive=no
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try the following `.pkla`

```
[First disable all users]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=*
ResultActive=no
ResultInactive=no
ResultAny=no

[Then enable wheel group]
Identity=unix-group:wheel
Action=*
ResultActive=auth_admin
ResultInactive=no
ResultAny=no
```

in conjunction with a modification of the `AdminIdentities`, configured in a file under `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority.conf.d/`.
I have the following two files

#### 50-localauthority.conf

```
[Configuration]
AdminIdentities=unix-user:0
```

and

#### 51-ubuntu-admin.conf

```
[Configuration]
AdminIdentities=unix-group:sudo;unix-group:admin
```

The second one override the first, and force to use `sudo` (and the old `admin`) group. Remove the second file and you are leaved with a root password request.

Comment: `unix-group` may not work on some buggy polkit versions. In that case, use `unix-user` instead.